# How to make vscode-ruby to find bundler in an asdf-vm environment?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, asdf-vm

I'm trying to get the vscode-ruby running within an asdf-vm environment. It's possible to set the path to bundler in the settings. I've set it to:

- `bundle`
- `/home/user/.asdf/shims/bundle`

If I load a ruby file the extension complains:

```
/bin/sh: bundle: command not found
```

[image: Error message]

My environment is:

```
Version: 1.39.2
Commit: 6ab598523be7a800d7f3eb4d92d7ab9a66069390
Date: 2019-10-18T10:58:05.878Z
Electron: 4.2.12
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.3.8-arch1-1
```

How can I get it to work?